# Changing font-size on root doesn't affect @media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, root, font-size

I'm working in a page that has

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

That means `1rem = 10px` instead of `1rem = 16px` So far, so good.

The problem is that it doesn't affect `@media queries`.

```
/*
it should change at 600px and not 960px.
the @media ignores the 62.5%;
*/
@media (min-width: 60rem) {
    .el {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

Check this codepen to see the issue.

http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/bqGZjE

I tested on a retina monitor, with Chrome and Firefox. On Safari the issue doesn't happen.

Any solution?

Comment: It is working on 960px. in Windows chrome 1920 resolution. I have resized my browser to 960px and it's working proper.

Comment: I want it to change at 600px, not 960px because the font-size is 62.5%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. 
In `@media` you need to use `em` and it will always read the default browser size, ignoring your custom `font-size`. The same doesn't happen with `rem`.
So in this case, you need to set `37.5em` (600/16), and it will change the at 600px in every browser including safari.

https://zellwk.com/blog/media-query-units/

> (...) the only unit that performed consistently across all four browsers is `em`. There aren’t any differences between em and rem with the exception of bugs found on Safari.
>   (...) Unfortunately, px media queries remained at 400px in the third experiment, which makes it a no-go if you intend to support users who change their browser’s font-size value.
>   Hence, my conclusion after these experiments is: Use `em` media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
    .el {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also just found out in mac safari media queries using `rem` just not reflecting and good research on `em` and `rem` really nice.

Answer (score 0):

No. It doesn't have to do anything with you `html` `font-size` or your `.el` `font-size`. Because 1rem is 16px. So you have to calculate it as per 16px.

```
@media (min-width: 37.5rem) {
    .el {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

This would be your 600px media queries breaks.

Comment: Nop, that way if you open the codepen on safari, it will render with 375px and not 600px because safari can read 62.5%.

Comment: I think, You should not test this with codepen made code. Just create a local file and add meta viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` and test this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<div class="el">
    hey there
</div>

// =========== basic template =========== //
$safeArea: 1rem;
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

// ======== actual codepen code ========= //

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

.el {
    background: red;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

/* it should change at 600 px and not 960px.
the @media ignores the 62.5%;
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 60rem) {
    .el {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

see this codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJbxOQ

Comment: Hmm, nop, it still changes at 960px, I want to change it at 600px